# Sorting a list with certain conditions

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering, sorting

I have this List1:

```
{{-0.5, 1.3, 1.2, 8.3, 2.1, 0.1, 5}, {-0.9, 
  1.2, 1.1, 9.4, 2.1, 0.1, 3}, {-0.6, 1.1, 
  1.0, 9.0, 2.0, 0.1, 2}, {-0.4, 1.0, 1.2, 
  20.7, 2.9, 0.1, 7}}
```

Is it possible to rewrite List1 into List2 without loops?
List2:

```
{{2, -0.6}, {3, -0.9}, {5, -0.5}, {7, -0.4}}
```

2, 3, 5, 7 - these are the last elements in each of the sublists in List1.
-0.6, -0.9, -0.5, -0.4 - these are the first elements in each of the sublists in List1.
And finally, the sublists in List2 sorted in ascending order of the first element.
Thanks for all comments!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Sort[list1[[All, {-1, 1}]]]
(*    {{2, -0.6}, {3, -0.9}, {5, -0.5}, {7, -0.4}}    *)
```